# Using JQuery, how can I check if the content inside span tag in a div tag contains "@" character?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to check if the content (adrianray@yahoo.com) inside the first `span` tag (`class="name"`) contains the "@" character or not. It has below as you see.

```
<div class="nameMail">
    <span class="name">adrianray@yahoo.com</span>
    <span class="mail">adrianray@yahoo.com</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$('.nameMail span').first().text().indexOf('@') !== -1`

Comment: Forgot saying this is inside cshtml page. How the @ should be included inside the indexOf('')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('.nameMail span.name').each(function ()
{
     if($(this).text().indexOf('@') != -1)
     {
       alert("Yes");
     }
});
```

Comment: if($(this).text().indexOf('@@') != -1) as this is cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('.name').text().indexOf('@') !== -1 ) {
    // contain @
} else {
    // doesn't contain @
}
```

Comment: The only problem is @ character. This is MVC. Inside cshtml page gives error because @ is special character. I tried for letter 'a'. It works. Now, how to escape?

Comment: @ might be encoded as html code &#64; by your server-side application. Btw this code works for me ( both Google Chrome and Firefox ) with both @ and &#64; in html code.

Comment: Maybe it's me but I noticed the if condition returns true for any character. And I just doubled @ symbol: @@. It works fine with @Bala's answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x1 = $('.name').text();
if(x1.indexOf("@") > -1){
   alert('Found it');
}else{
   alert('Not present');
}
```